# How to apply StringFormat to a wpf textbox conditionally

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have a textbox which gets populated from DB. The DB value has to be string formatted which is happening due to the StringFormat. This value can be changed bu the user. If the user edit the value in a different format the String Formatter should not reformat it.

How can i achieve this?

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtStartDate" 
         Height="24" Width="80" Padding="0" MaxLength="10" 
         Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='ddd, ddMMM',
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}"
         />
```

The textbox is a custom control in the actual project.

E.g.
DB sends a value as May30 it is converted to 30May and displayed in the textbox, this is as expected.
Now if user changes it back to May30 this should not be converted it and May30 should be displayed.
What is actually happening is that the value is formatted back to 30May, so want to prevent the formatting once a user has touched the value.

Answer (score 0):

When writing WPF, it is *always* best to provide your views/`UserControl`s and/or `Window`s with the exact data that they require. With your requirements, I would add some extra properties to simplify this problem. I'd need one `DateTime` property, one `string` property and one `bool` property. The `DateTime` property obviously sources the date from the `DatePicker`, the `string` one outputs the displayed value and the `bool` property specifies whether to apply the string format to the date value or not. You could try something like this:

```
public DateTime Date // Bind with DatePicker
{
    get { return date; }
    set 
    {
        date = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
        IsFormatted = YourLogicHere();
    }
}

public bool IsFormatted { get; set; }

public string DateValue
{
    get { return IsFormatted ? Date.ToString("ddd, ddMMM") : Date.ToString(); }
}
```

So the `DateValue` property is what is displayed in the UI and will either output the default `DateTime` value, or the formatted value, dependant upon the value of the `IsFormatted` property. The basic idea is to set this `IsFormatted` property to `true` or `false`, dependant on your requirements.

I think you said dependant upon the user changing the value or something, so when the user changes the value, you can set this to `true` and then it will only output the unformatted version of the date. You might need to add another property or alter something from this example to implement your requirements, but you should have got the idea by now and I trust that you will be able to complete it from here.

Comment: Deleted my answer as you are right,  it was more of a suggestion - I began with an answer and it became less so as I re-read the question and my thoughts changed. However, in the interest of trying to find a solution for the author, I am not sure your solution really addresses the issue either. The problem seems to be maintaining the users entered date format once an edit is made - but this solution simply returns one of two formats and doesn't take into account the how the user has actually chosen to enter the date. What do you think? Maybe I am interpreting the issue wrongly.

Comment: I don't think that the user will be entering a string format... I *could* be wrong.